# Get IDs of nodes via the edge collection only

Tags: arangodb

I am writing an application that stores external data in ArangoDB for further processing inside the application. Let's assume I am talking about `Photos` in `Photosets` here.

Due to the nature of used APIs, I need to fetch `Photosets` befor I can load `Photos`. In the `Photosets` API reply, there is a list of `Photo` IDs that I later use to fetch the `Photo`s. So I created an edge collection called `photosInSets` and store the edges between `Photosets` and `Photos`, although the `Photos` are not there yet.

Later on, I need to get a list of all needed `Photo`s to load them via the API. All IDs are numeric. At the moment, I use the following AQL query to fetch the IDs of all required `Photos`:

```
FOR edge
IN photosInSets
RETURN DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(
  SUBSTITUTE(edge._from, "photos/", "")
)
```

However... this does not look like a nice solution. I'd like to (at least) get rid of the string operation to remove the collection name. What's the nice way to do that?

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can find this is with a join on the `photosInSets` edge collection back to the photos collection.

Try a query that looks like this:

```
FOR e IN photoInSets
LET item = (FOR v IN photos FILTER e._from == v._id RETURN v._key)
RETURN item
```

This joins the _from reference in `photoInSets` with the _id back in the `photos` collection, then pulls the _key from `photos`, which won't have the collection name as part of it.

Have a look at a photo item and you'll see there is _id, _key and _rev as system attributes. It's fine to use the _key value if you want a string, it's not necessary to implement your own unique id unless there is a burning reason why you can't expose _key.

With a little manipulation, you could even return an array of objects stating which photo._key is a member of which photoSet, you'll just have to have two LET commands and return both results. One looking at the Photo, one looking at the photoSet.

I'm not official ArangoDB support, but I'm interested if they have another way of doing this.

Comment: The thing is... as I wrote, the photos are not there yet, the `photos` collection is empty. I use the mentioned query to get a list of `Photo`s I need to fetch, so I cannot join the empty collection. Thanks, though!

Comment: OK, So you are creating Photosets, and photos, then later on adding relationships between them to photosInSets? In order to add a relationship in photosInSets, you'll need to have valid _from and _to values for that table, so the Photosets entry and photos entry will need to be there.

Comment: I know the IDs of the photos in the sets, but that's all. So I have enough information to create the edges, but not the documents. Well, I could just create an empty photo document and update it later, though...

Comment: So it sounds like you need a few things. Query to fetch PhotoSets, query to  fetch Photos, query to fetch Photos in PhotoSet of a specific key. If someone queries /api/photosets they will get the keys of the photo sets. Then they query /api/photos and they get photo ids. Then they call /api/photosets/{photosetID}/add/{photoID} and it adds that photo to the photosInSets where ._from is the photoset referenced by {photosetID} and the ._to is the photo referenced from {photoID}.  You only need to use the photosInSets edge collection when you actually add a photo to a photoSet.

Comment: Please note that until ArangoDB 3.0 (currently in alpha) the `_from` and `_to` attributes of edges are immutable - hence you can't modify them once you wrote the document. So you 'd at least need to be able to predict the ID of the vertex you want to point to.